# LinkedIn signin emailAddress retrieval

Tags: c#, linkedin-api

Using the below endpoint to retrieve the emailAddress in URN format as per new V2 guidelines:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))
```

Get the response in the format:

```
{
    "elements": [
        {
            "handle": "urn:li:emailAddress:<id>",
            "handle~": {
                "emailAddress": "email@provider.com"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Using a rest sharp client, we have received the correct response, but how to deserialize(in C#) the response in above format to retrieve only the email address?

Have tried to use the projection : `projection=(elements*(handle~(vanityName)))` and try to get the field directly : `q=members&fields=emailAddress` , but get "not enough permissions to access field vanityName for GET /clientAwareEmailAddresses/ not enough permissions to access field emailAddress for GET-members /emailAddress" error

Have used the scope `r_liteprofile r_emailaddress` in the authorization request.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
jsonContent = JObject.Parse(content);
var profileEmail = jsonContent["elements"][0]["handle~"]["emailAddress"].ToString();
```